# how to overcome memory limit on vector allocation in rust code assembled to WASM binaries

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, rust-wasm, wasm-pack

Update: created a small test app (react calling wasm rust code) but cant recreate rust exception, however this one liner is an extract from bit bigger function and I am still on to find what particular combo is leading to this exception

https://github.com/zkbitcoin/react-rust-wasm-vector-test

instructions:

a) clone
b) rustup component add rust-src --toolchain nightly-2022-11-17-x86_64-apple-darwin
c) yarn build:wasm
d) yarn build
e) yarn start

I compiled this sample rust code to WASM (note this one liner runs fine in standard non WASM environment)

```rust
let s = vec![vec![1usize; 131072]; 38];
```

This code fails in Chrome with:

```
rust_alloc_error_handler ... at alloc::vec::from_elem
```

Does anyone know how to overcome it? I tried both default and wee_alloc, both are failing.

Comment: You'll need to add more info cause your code runs fine here. Also check the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) help section for more infos what to include.

Comment: its bit hard cause this would be in WASM environment (browser) assembled by wasm-pack (and code is one liner) let s = vec![vec![1usize; 131072]; 38];

Comment: If you wan't us to be able to help you you'll have to provide more detail, wether it's hard or not.

Comment: fair enough will create small project with cargo and env details stand by

Comment: @cafce25 cant recreate problem with a bare bone code (updated main thread with it) issue originally came from me running much larger project

this is the outliner of the problem in main program ,

https://github.com/SoraSuegami/halo2_rsa/issues/1

halo2_rsa calls https://github.com/privacy-scaling-explorations/halo2/blob/main/halo2_proofs/src/plonk/permutation/keygen.rs#L23

which does that vector allocation and fails (but there is "clone" of other objects going) and so its not easy could be web assembly created fault code which I know its rare...

Comment: and so I will try hard to find that faulty combination and update template app I have created (really minimal) but if @cafce25 others you see something that is a red flag in this please do let know (vector allocation faults in that function below)

pub(crate) fn new(n: usize, p: &Argument) -> Self {
...

Answer (score 0):

In the original code I moved `vec![vec![1usize; n]; p.columns.len()]` size assignment to be first in the function, this got rid of mem alloc exception.

Resolved all my issues, this was also helpful (added `--max-memory=4294967296` to `RUSTFLAGS`)

[Only 1/4th of max memory available when rust wasm compiled with +atomics flag webassembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72334989/only-1-4th-of-max-memory-available-when-rust-wasm-compiled-with-atomics-flag-we)